# Is there any way to simplify restrict access to specific source IP in apache httpd.conf file

Tags: apache

For example, this is my httpd.conf:

```
...
<Location /a>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from x.x.x.x
    (and other "Allow from x.x.x.x")
</Location>

<Location /b>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from x.x.x.x
    (and other "Allow from x.x.x.x")
</Location>

(and other locations with same ip restrict)
...
```

Inside the `Location` tags are the same ip restrict, and there are hundreds ips. So how to simplify it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of placing the "allow from" inside each location, you can place it in the "" block of the document root.
Another option could be to use a rewrite rule and place it at the virtualhost level (or in the httpd.conf, according to your configuration):

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^214.53.25.(6[4-9]|7[0-9]|8[0-9]|9[0-9])$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^214.53.25.1([0-1][0-9]|2[0-8])$
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```